# How to get a value returned from a method in a shared library in declarative syntax?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm using pipeline declarative syntax and I need to get a value returned from a method in a shared library

```
    pipeline{
        String label= new Define.getLabel()
        agent (label ${label})
        // stages, options ...
    }
```

Comment: It would help to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

This should work. I didn't test with a shared library but it works the same (of course you have to import the shared library with `@Library('library-name')_` and your script should be stored there. (Mine is in the pipeline).

My script is very easy. `GetLabel` wil just return `"docker"` but you can make this more complex with conditional states.

I call the method and save the output in `labelID`. So `labelID` contains `"docker"`. I read the content of `labelID` when I specify the label I want to use.

```
def labelID = getLabel()

pipeline {
    agent { node { label labelID } }

    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "hallo"'
            }
        }
    }
}

def getLabel(){
    return 'docker'
}
```

This pipeline has run on the slave with label `'docker'`.